# Make a counter "update" exercise in environment exercise

Tags: environments, counters

I wrote a book in about year 2010. Now I want to add (update) some exercises and count all updated Exercises. But I only can `Update 2014`. How can I make `Update 0ne 2014`, `Update two 2014`, ... or `Update_01_2014`, `Update_02_2014`, ...?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[chapter]
\newenvironment{ex*}
  {\renewcommand\theex{\thechapter.\arabic{ex}\rlap{$^*$}}\ex}
  {\endex}

\newenvironment{New}
  {\renewcommand\theex{\thechapter.\arabic{ex}{$^{\text{(Update 2014)}}$}}\ex}
  {\endex}  
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{ex}
This is an Exercise
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
This is an Exercise
\end{ex}
\begin{ex*}
This is a difficult Exercise
\end{ex*}
\begin{New}
This is an update Exercise
\end{New}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a counter. You can adjust the formatting as you wish.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[chapter]
\newenvironment{ex*}
  {\renewcommand\theex{\thechapter.\arabic{ex}\rlap{$^*$}}\ex}
  {\endex}

\newcounter{updatecounter}

\newenvironment{New}
  {\stepcounter{updatecounter}
   \renewcommand\theex{\thechapter.\arabic{ex}{$^{\text{(Update
           \arabic{updatecounter}, 2014)}}$}}\ex}
  {\endex}  
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{ex}
This is an Exercise
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
This is an Exercise
\end{ex}
\begin{ex*}
This is a difficult Exercise
\end{ex*}
\begin{New}
This is an updated Exercise
\end{New}
\begin{New}
This is another updated Exercise
\end{New}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Ethan Bolker If I want `Update 1, 2014`. How must I do?

Comment: I just added a comma in the right place in the answer.